# Creating a Nodejs chat application

Tags: nodejs

I am creating a nodejs chat application, and I am in the process of setting up the environment. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I could understand that I need `nodejs` and `socket.io` to be installed on my PC before creating the application.

How can I install these packages: `nodejs` and `socket.io` on my system, so that I can start building my chat application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

socket.io has a chat rooms feature. For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654820/nodejs-and-socket-io-chat-rooms/8655260#8655260) to the question [nodejs and socket.io chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654820/nodejs-and-socket-io-chat-rooms) at Stack Overflow.

To install nodejs and socket.io from the terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install socket.io
```

**Update:** In Ubuntu 14.04 and later the [node snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657) is more up-to-date and npm is bundled with it.

In order to test if socket.io is working, try this tutorial: [Get Started: Chat application](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/). If you get an error message when following the tutorial that says: `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile` then replace sendFile with sendfile (all lowercase), and of course you should also use the command `nodejs` to start Node.js in interactive mode in Ubuntu instead of `node`.

<sub>[socket.io - node.js realtime framework server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io)</sub>