# How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?

Tags: software-installation, nodejs, npm

I noticed over at the https://nodejs.org/ website that node is currently at v 0.12.0.

Can someone let me know how to install the latest version of node together with npm (terminal commands please)?

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo apt-get install nodejs`?

Comment: ^ it installs 1.10.0.

Comment: @siliconrockstar that actually installed v0.10.25 on my 14.04 LTS

Comment: In ubuntu 16 use `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Answer (score 269, accepted):

#### Fresh installation

Use the NodeSource PPA. For details look at [the installation instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall). First, choose the Node.js version you need and add the sources for it:

```
v=8   # set to 4, 5, 6, ... as needed
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$v.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Then install the Node.js package.

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

P.S.: `curl` package must be installed on server for these code lines.

#### Upgrading

If you have `nodejs` already installed and want to update, then first remove current instalation and install it again using scripts above.

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
```

Comment: NodeSource use two separate PPA: one for 0.10.X version and for 0.12.X. In addition, it contains last npm package.

Comment: Appreciate the response 23W so how would I install latest stable 0.12.4 using NodeSource?

Comment: @tonsils 
I have added the example code.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: didn't work for me. After running `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -` then installing `nodejs` I ended up with `v0.10`

Comment: ^ I resinstalled using nodesource and it worked!  (`apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm` then redo the above)

Comment: @Coombesy Try reading script at that link and adding links to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` file manually.

Comment: Did something happen to nodesource? The website / github repo seems fine, but the curl command gives `W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404`

Comment: Curling into root shell is so wrong in so many ways.

Comment: This installs it as nodejs instead of node. You can symlink it to `node` by running: `sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/sbin/node`

Comment: Answer by Guss below should have been the accepted answer. This is not the recommended way to do it.

Comment: Another formal source for instructions: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: This is such a dangerous idea. There are so many ways this could go wrong; you should never curl arbitrary data into a root shell. You could so easily compromise your system. Guss' answer should be accepted.

Comment: ok, but what about the latest version of npm?

Comment: @AlexanderMills the answer provided below (https://askubuntu.com/a/711976/389358) will get you the latest version of nodejs from NodeSource -- this package includes the latest version of npm as well.

Comment: It is a little bit irritating to me to download a bash script from some website that might be hacked and run it with root permissions

Answer (score 179):

Generally speaking, loading arbitrary data from a URL into a root shell session is not a good idea and I wish people would stop peddling it as a solution for everything - "Please just run this script I'm sending you, and also while we're at it - I have a bridge you'd probably be interested in purchasing".

As an alternative, here's the "Ubuntu Way" of doing the same, where you can see how the system is being updated and know what repositories and what keys are added to your system configuration:

```
curl https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x $(lsb_release -sc) main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

And here's the "post [deprecation of apt-key](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-key.8.en.html) way" of doing the same thing:

```
curl https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodejs.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```

This is for the latest (at time of writing) Nodejs version 7. Other versions can also be gotten with a simple change to the repo URL - consult nodesource.com documentation for details.

Comment: I totally agree with your statement, but isn't adding a new repository to apt, the same as running some unknown script? (Though I understand the script in every other answer here, is actually adding that repo by itself)

Comment: The script is adding the repo by itself, and also doing god knows what. It may be completely benign now, but who knows what DNS hijackers or web site exploiters will do in the future? Adding a repo is not the same as running a script of the internet because by itself it does not download any executable code or runs it - it will only do so in response to a specific apt-get install, which will verify the package was signed with a the nodesource key - which is hopefully kept much more securely then the nodesource domain or website. APT security is excellent and has a good track record.

Comment: The commands need `sudo`, and even then, I get node 0.10.25 installed, not 5.5.0, the current version. `Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404`

Comment: @Dan, It appears you are running Ubuntu 15.04 (utopic) which is not supported by Node Source, so you get 0.10 from utopic's repositories. Node Source only support LTS releases and the latest non-LTS. Because you are not on an LTS release you're expected to upgrade to the latest version when it came out last October. So either do that, or hack it by changing the `$(lsb_release -c)` release autodetection bit to one of the supported releases and deal with the consequences.

Comment: This is also helpful when trying to ansibilize your dev box.  I'm not going to curl a bash script to get the appropriate ppa for that...  Thanks so much!

Comment: Good answer, but....where's the bridge?

Comment: @PaulDraper: Ask nodesource, they're the ones selling bridges they don't own. My `apt-get` solution is the straight dope.

Comment: awesome answer ! in case anyone else is wondering, it **just works** for newer versions - e.g: just replace _7_ with _9_

Comment: also consider changing npm's folder, to avoid having to `sudo` when installing global packages: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory

Comment: Ooh, thank You so much! I've got an error, when try to install nodejs into root shell. And only Your way worked for me! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 37):

**Node.js v4.x:**

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

source: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall

Comment: Curling into root shell is so wrong in so many ways.

Comment: after that I have to run `sudo apt-get install -y npm` to install npm
but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

If you want to update inside `npm`, you can use the `n` command:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo npm install npm@latest
```

This installs the n package which you can use to switch NodeJS-Versions and uses it. Comparison to the alternative NVM and command options are at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666010/n-or-nvm-for-managing-node-versions-is-keeping-global-modules-for-each-version). There is also a [blog post](http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-fundamentals-how-to-upgrade-the-node-js-version/).

Comment: I've add a NVM step-by-step at: https://askubuntu.com/a/971612/52975

Comment: I'm pretty new to npm and nvm; I'm trying to install npm inside a python virtualenv; does it matter whether I use npm or nvm? 
`nvm install lts/carbon` installs npm and node for me. 
How is this different from the above commands which you shared?

Comment: @kRazzyR: you get to choose whether to use `nvm` or `n` to update NodeJS and `npm`.  In both cases, you use `npm` to install node packages.

Answer (score 11):

#### NVM (Node Version manager)

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

NVM installs both the latest stable node and npm for you

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
npm --version
```

Now test it out with a dummy package:

```
npm install --global vaca
vaca
```

Since the sourcing has to be done for every new shell, the install script hacks adds some auto sourcing to the end of your `.barshrc`. That works, but I prefer to remove the auto-added one and add my own:

```
f="$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
if [ -r "$f" ]; then
  . "$f" &>'/dev/null'
  nvm use --lts &>'/dev/null'
fi
```

Advantages:

- allows you to use multiple versions of Node and without sudo
- is analogous to Ruby RVM and Python Virtualenv, widely considered best practice in Ruby and Python communities
- downloads a pre-compiled binary where possible, and if not it downloads the source and compiles one for you

We can easily switch node versions with:

```
nvm install 0.9.0
nvm install 0.9.9
nvm use 0.9.0
node --version
#v0.9.0
nvm use 0.9.9
node --version
#v0.9.9
```

You can then use a git tracked `.nvmrc` file to indicate the node version required for a given project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869959/how-do-i-specify-a-local-version-of-node-for-a-project/54503474#54503474

With this setup, you get for example:

```
which node
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/bin/node
```

and:

```
which vaca
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/bin/vaca
```

and if we want to use the globally installed module:

```
npm link vaca
node -e 'console.log(require.resolve("vaca"))'
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/.nvm/versions/node/v0.9.0/lib/node_modules/vaca/index.js
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636367/nodejs-require-a-global-module-package
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/how-do-i-import-global-modules-in-node-i-get-error-cannot-find-module-module

so we see that everything is completely contained inside the specific node version.

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 8):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
# Then install with:
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Here you can find more info: [Node.js v0.12, io.js, and the NodeSource Linux Repositories](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories)

Answer (score 8):

To install NPM,

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Then for Node,

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 0.xx.x  // here is the version what you want..
```

This command will install node based on your version you want..

Answer (score 7):

For version 5.x [According to PPA](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall):

```
apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 4):

Node.js is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Specific to Node.js, developers can choose from one of the currently supported releases and get regular automatic updates directly from NodeSource. Node.js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18 are currently available, with the Snap Store being updated within hours, or minutes of a Node.js release.

Node can be installed with a single command, for example:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable
```

The node snap can be accessed by the command `node`, for example:

```
$ node -v  
v11.5.0
```

An up-to-date version of npm will installed as part of the node snap. npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. After installing the node snap run the following command to enable npm update checking:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/your-username/.config
```

Replace  **`your-username`** in the above command with your own username. Then run `npm -v` to check if the version of npm is up-to-date. As an example I checked that npm was up-to-date, checked the version of an already installed package named yarn with the command `npm list yarn` and then updated the existing yarn package to the latest version with the command `npm update yarn`

Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example:

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=11/stable
```

Users can test bleeding-edge versions of Node.js that can be installed from the latest edge channel by switching with:

```
sudo snap switch node --edge
```

This approach is only recommended for those users who are willing to participate in testing and bug reporting upstream.

#### Node.js LTS schedule

| Release | Status | Codename | Initial release | LTS Start | Maintenance Start | Maintenance End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.x | EOL | Boron | 2016-04-26 | 2016-10-18 | 2018-04-30 | 2019-04-30 |
| 7.x | EOL |  | 2017-05-30 |  |  | 2017-06-30 |
| 8.x | EOL | Carbon | 2016-10-25 | 2017-10-31 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 9.x | EOL |  | 2017-10-01 |  |  | 2018-06-30 |
| 10.x | EOL | Dubnium | 2018-04-24 | 2018-10-30 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-04-30 |
| 11.x | EOL |  | 2018-10-23 |  |  | 2019-06-01 |
| 12.x | Maintenance LTS | Erbium | 2019-04-23 | 2019-10-21 | 2020-11-301 | 2022-04-30 |
| 13.x | EOL |  | 2019-10-22 |  |  | 2020-06-01 |
| 14.x | Maintenance LTS | Fermium | 2020-04-21 | 2020-10-27 | 2021-10-30 | 2023-04-30 |
| 16.x | Active LTS | Gallium | 2021-04-20 | 2021-10-26 | 2022-10-18 | 2024-04-30 |
| 17.x | Current |  | 2021-10-19 |  | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-01 |
| 18.x | Current |  | 2022-04-19 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-10-18 | 2025-04-30 |

Answer (score 4):

You can install latest version very easily using below instruction.

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -

Vesion 7.x is the latest version of node.

> sudo apt-get install nodejs

Above line will install nodejs.

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

This will install essential modules for nodejs to run properly.

Now check whether nodejs installed correctly at your end

> nodejs -v

This will return installed nodejs version.

> npm -v

This will return installed npm version. Hope it helps....

Source : [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) will show you how to install nodejs using some other methods as well.

Comment: Why install `build-essential`?

Comment: The nodejs package contains the nodejs binary as well as npm. However, in order for some npm packages to work (such as those that require building from source), you will need to install the **build-essentials** package

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 15.10 you can download the .deb package form [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/i386/nodejs/download)

```
node --version
v4.2.3
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
# Download
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.5/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64.tar.xz

# Install
cd /usr/local
tar --strip-components 1 -xJf ~/Downloads/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64.tar.xz

# Verify
node -v
npm version
```

[Source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/10/install-nodejs-npm-linux/)

Comment: For me, in `Ubuntu 18.04`, `cd /usr` worked instead of `cd /usr/local`.

Comment: @Miron `/usr` would work but you should install software manually to `/usr/local` for maintainability. See [/usr/bin vs /usr/local/bin on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8656/54675) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Just a spin-off of the answer by @23W (accepted answer).

This is just the contents of the script, just to avoid doing curl to root shell.

```
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x $(lsb_release -c -s) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x $(lsb_release -c -s) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 3):

Download `nodejs` from https://nodejs.org/

To install from a terminal:

```
cd /usr/local
tar --strip-components 1 -xJf ~/Downloads/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Video Explanation](https://youtu.be/OT7QOFvs9Lk)

---

NVM is very simple to install and allows you to easily switch node versions. From the [github repository](https://github.com/creationix/nvm):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

downloads and runs the installation script

```
nvm ls-remote
```

to see the available versions. Say you want to install version 8.9.4

```
nvm install 8.9.4
```

and you're done.

To install another version and use it (say 9.6.1)

```
nvm install 9.6.1
nvm alias default 9.6.1
```

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to install latest nodejs and npm is using the [installation binaries](https://superuser.com/a/52750) archive provided on nodejs' website.

This might quickly become your new favorite way too. Works like a charm. It involves 1 download and 1 command. Done. NO errors [the multiple times I've done this]. Didn't need to uninstall existing stuff beforehand.

## Installing nodejs via Binaries

---

At first remove the installed version: (if exists)

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

#### Download

https://nodejs.org/en/download/stable/

Download Linux Binaries.

- I had to extract the tar.xz to a folder and then re-compress as tar.gz

#### Install

```
sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf /path/to/downloaded/tar/node-vYOURVERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

#### Verify

```
node -v
npm --version
```

#### Source

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/10/install-nodejs-npm-linux/

Comment: Why re-compress as tar.gz? `tar` supports `--xz` - and `-C /usr/local` to let `tar` do the `cd` for you.

Answer (score 1):

This approach allows you easily delete Node.JS, keep different versions and provide the commands to all the system users.

Download the [stable version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) of [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), uncompress it, and move it into `/opt`.

In case you wish to install different versions, you can rename the folder according to its version code:

```
/opt/node/6.9.1
```

Since only root can change files in `/opt`/, if you don't wish to call invoke `sudo` every time you need to modify a file, change the group permission:

```
chgrp adm -R /opt/node/10.15.3
```

Then create file `/etc/profile.d/node.sh` if the following content:

```
export NODE_HOME=/opt/node/10.15.3

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${NODE_HOME}/include
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=${NODE_HOME}/include
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${NODE_HOME}/lib
export MANPATH=${NODE_HOME}/share/man:${MANPATH}

export PATH=${NODE_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Logout and login and X-Window will reload all profile configurations.

If you had a previous versions installed, to avoid library conflicts run:

```
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update Package Manager**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Adding NodeJS PPAs**

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

**Installing NodeJS and NPM**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Here, I Wrote a Complete Blog post about [Installing NodeJS and NPM in Ubuntu. 
Click Here to Read](https://webcheerz.com/install-nodejs-and-npm-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Curling into a root shell is a really bad thing to do in general do to the huge number of security issues this opens up, I would recommend that you update your blog post and your answer to not do this.

Answer (score -1):

**Updating Package Manager**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Adding PPA**

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
```

**Installing NodeJS and NPM**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

For Reference : [Installing NodeJS in Ubuntu - WebCheerz](https://webcheerz.com/install-nodejs-and-npm-on-ubuntu/)