# How to install node 0.10.40 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, nodejs

I'm trying to follow this instruction (from [How to Install the Latest Versions of NodeJS and NPM for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts/711976#711976?newreg=2645d8ec8d544afaa1a600b0bd452a60)):

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 68576280
apt-add-repository "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x $(lsb_release -sc) main"
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
```

Where it is mentioned that I can replace that URL with a different repository. I need a version greater than 0.10.37 - which is the max version the chris-lea repository seems to provide - but lower than 5.x. (I have removed the chris-lea repository).

However, I'm not at all sure what the URL actually has to refer to, when looking at this link:
https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.40/

Then, when I try to install node v0.12 with these commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I get 0.10.25.

How can I either: remove all traces of node from apt-get so that I can install it manually, or update the apt-get repository details to get the correct version?

Comment: Hi Zach Smith , refer this you will get some idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898001/installing-a-specific-node-version-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a set of scripts and needed to fix it to work. Source here: https://gist.github.com/msporny/5019c4bed5415b745edd

1) Setup apt for 0.10

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | sudo bash -`

2) Find the exact version you have setup

`apt-cache policy nodejs`

3) Install that version of 0.10. For me I did

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs=0.10.48-*`