# Install the latest version of node.js

Tags: nodejs

I'm trying to install `Quasar framework` in using `sudo npm install -g quasar-cli`. I realised that I need the latest version of `node.js`. I want to install the latest recommend version of `node.js`, but I'm not familiar with that kind of installation. Could anyone be able to tell me what do I have to do to install that software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Install the Latest Versions of NodeJS and NPM for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

You may also want to install the build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

According to [the nodejs website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)