# Setup angular4 project

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, npm

I'm having troubles with setting up an angular4 project.
I use [this tutorial](https://coursetro.com/courses/12/Learn-Angular-4-from-Scratch/lessons/1).

So when I type the first command:

```
node -v
```

I get v4.8.3, this is my first problem, how to update this to 6.10 in ubuntu.

Next command in the guide is

```
ng -v
```

I get this weird output

```
Mg++ version:
    Mg++ 1.5beta1 (formerly MicroGnuEmacs Adv.)
```

How can I change this so I can go trough with the setup for the angular4 project?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts for getting a newer `node` version.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: yes,  still having problems, is there a way to remove npm and everything with it? Or maybe Ubuntu back to init?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove ng
```

Then try `ng -v` if you have already installed angular 4.

Otherwise first use the command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli.
```