# How to install AngularJS on Ubuntu

Tags: language-support, javascript

Can someone help me with a step by step guide to install AngularJS on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have `nodejs` and `npm` installed:

```
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

Note that this will install nodejs 4 and npm 3, but for plain angularjs this should be enough.

Then, in a node package (you can create one by running `npm init` in a directory, if you don't have any yet), install the `angularjs` module using

```
npm install --save angular
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Install nodejs and npm in latest version (simple no need to explain it). For installing the latest versions of both: [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657)
2. For angular run these commands in the terminal:

   ```
   npm install -g angular-cli
   ng new Project_Name  
   cd Project_Name  
   ng serve # ng serve will start the server by looking at some config file.
   ```
3. Check on `localhost:4200` it shows "app works".

Answer (score 0):

To install Angular JS, make sure your PC has a stable version(LTS version) of **NodeJS** and **npm** installed.

To **check for Node and npm**:

1. Open your terminal or press **`Ctrl + Alt + T`**
2. Run `node -v`
3. Run `npm -v`

If not found, first **install NodeJS**. Or if older version as compared to the LTS version, first **uninstall the older version** and then follow these steps:

**Node.js v12.x:**

***NOTE:*** If you are using Ubuntu Precise or Debian Wheezy, you might want to read about running Node.js >= 6.x on older distros

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Also, if you want any other version of Node, click this link: [Github NodeJS](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions)

Now, you can **install Angular**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

This will install the latest version of Angular.

If you need an older version:

```
npm -g install @angular/cli@1.5
or
npm -g install @angular/cli@2
or
npm -g install @angular/cli@1
or
npm -g install @angular/cli@5
.
.
```

> **NOTE:** Having older version of node and installing Angular, `ng -v` will return: [image: this warning]

After installing AngularJS check with: `ng version`

The result should be like this: [image]

**Namaste**