# 404 not found when apt-get Install npm in Azure Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, azure

I've create a Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS (published by Canonical) in Azure

When execute

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

it get error message like

```
Err:6 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 cpp-5 amd64 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5
  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/cpp-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
```

Could I replace azure.archive.ubuntu.com server address in etc/apt/sources.list with archive.ubuntu.com or old-releases.ubuntu.com? or any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/712813

Comment: I found that run `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`, it will fetch missing part from `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`, then run `sudo apt-get install npm` would work. so no need to change etc/apt/sources.list... just wonder why azure.archive.ubuntu.com does not have those missing part...

Comment: Not sure.  Where did you get the instructions then to use the `azure.archive.ubuntu.com`?  While I was looking at the `azure.archive.ubuntu.com` site, it appeared that the folders were last updated back in June of 2016.

Comment: Azure's ubuntu 16.04 vm (published by Canonical) is using `azure.archive.ubuntu.com` by default.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, I couldn't tell you why the applications were moved and no longer on the azure.archive.  Glad it is working for you though.  =)