# Problems installing Nodejs as a tarball

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

I downloaded NodeJS from the official website as a tarball and extracted it but I can't install it. The `BULDING.md` file says I should

```
./configure
```

then

```
make -j4
```

However, trying `./configure` inside the directory returns this error:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I solved this error (see the comments), but now after running `make -j4` I get this error:

```
node bin/npm-cli.js install marked --no-global --no-timing --no-save
node bin/npm-cli.js install marked-man --no-global --no-timing --no-save
bash: node: command not found
bash: node: command not found
Makefile:154: recipe for target 'node_modules/.bin/marked' failed
make: *** [node_modules/.bin/marked] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'node_modules/.bin/marked-man' failed
make: *** [node_modules/.bin/marked-man] Error 127
```

yet I have all dependencies (git, python, g++ and make). What am I missing here?
**Note**: I know I could install it using `apt` but I want to use this as part of learning.

Comment: The apt package is not up-to-date but the *node* snap package is kept up-to-date, so there's no longer any reason to compile the tarball. To install the *node* snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657

Comment: @karel good to hear, but what's wrong in this specific case?

Comment: The instructions for building Node.js in this specific case are contained in the BUILDING.md file in the tarball that you downloaded (node-v8.11.2.tar.gz). The commands to build Node.js are 1. `./configure` and 2.  `make -j4` The first command in your question is `.configure` which is wrong. It should be `./configure`

Comment: The `building.md` file is the one I was calling  `readme` file but those are the exact same instructions that I followed. Running `./configure` gives the above error.

Comment: You need to change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the configure file (so that bash can find it) before running the `./configure` command.

Comment: Thanks, now do you run both `./configure` and `make -j4` inside this directory? the latter command returns a couple of errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77794/discussion-between-karel-and-samuel).