# How to install node 10.13.0 LTS in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: nodejs, 18.10

On the official Node.js site they have a `tar.xz` file. I've extracted the file to my Downloads folder, but I am not sure what to do next. In one YouTube video I saw something like this:

```
sudo cp -r node/{bin,include,lib,share}/ /usr/
```

However, I think it's a bit outdated, in my opinion the node folder should go somewhere else than the `/usr/` folder, perhaps to `/usr/shared`?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PPA currently serves v8.11.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm) specifically this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657 tells how to install node version **10.13.0** in **18.10** in Ubuntu natively without downloading 3rd party packages or adding any PPA to your software sources.