# npm is not updating my node.js correctly

Tags: updates, nodejs, javascript

I have a js code that I want to run on a remote Ubuntu 16.04. And node -v is not showing the same results like nodejs -v. Well this happened after using npm update(the script I need to use asked for the most recent node version)
I just need to update to the last version of node that will run my js

I don't have an issue with the installation, I'm not sure but somewhere else, I found that I should have used NVM to update to a new version first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm)

Answer (score 0):

NVM handles the package for node. Just make sure NVM is configured to use the recent version.

you can use this command to check and configure.

```
nvm ls
nvm use 10.16.0
```