# Error while installing nativefier on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I attempted to install nativefier on my computer, but an error occurred with 
this present on the terminal :

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "nativefier" "-g"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/lenovo/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving to an older version of node and then retry installing it. According to this documentation, it's not an uncommon issue with Ubuntu 18.04 - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19348.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for V6.1.0.

Comment: If you install the node snap package with `sudo snap install node --classic --channel 6/stable && sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable` you can install version 6 alongside the latest version of node.js and use either version: https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657