# cordova installation error

Tags: lubuntu, npm

I am trying to install cordova on ubuntu using the following command

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordava
```

what does the following error means?

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-regex-88d497bc/package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string_decoder-91c3bf4f/package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-align-df792235/package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-regex-88d497bc/index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string_decoder-91c3bf4f/.npmignore'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-align-df792235/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-regex-88d497bc/license'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string_decoder-91c3bf4f/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-align-df792235/LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/subarg-35893add/test/arg.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-regex-88d497bc/readme.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/string_decoder-91c3bf4f/LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-align-df792235/index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/text-table-cd7a86ef/test/align.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/subarg-35893add/test/recursive.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/test/falafelTransformTest.coffee'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-align-df792235/CHANGELOG.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/text-table-cd7a86ef/test/ansi-colors.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/test/functionTransformTest.coffee'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/text-table-cd7a86ef/test/center.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/text-table-cd7a86ef/test/dotalign.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/test/loadConfigTest.coffee'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/text-table-cd7a86ef/test/doubledot.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/test/mocha.opts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/uglify-js-44befdbf/lib/minify.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/text-table-cd7a86ef/test/table.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/test/requireTransformTest.coffee'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/uglify-js-44befdbf/lib/mozilla-ast.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/test/skipFileTest.coffee'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-import-5bbd6267/lib/rules/prefer-default-export.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/test/stringTransformTest.coffee'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-import-5bbd6267/lib/rules/unambiguous.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/CHANGELOG.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-transform-tools-593d182b/run-test.sh'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/handlebars-ad286266/dist/amd/handlebars/compiler/helpers.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/browserify-0e18e2a3/test/global/node_modules/aaa/index.js'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: eslint-config-standard@11.0.0 (node_modules/cordova/node_modules/eslint-config-standard):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rd/-/eslint-config-st'

6114 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
6115 verbose node v11.10.0
6116 verbose npm  v6.8.0
6117 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...pNzlRJK3YppKVOnMZpBIf'
6118 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Maybe it means that you need git, but you haven't installed it. What are the results of `apt policy git` ? Also the apt version of node.js is woefully out of date. You should install the latest stable node snap package: https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657

Comment: @karel Here's the results 

git:
  Installed: 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4
  Candidate: 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4 500
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2.17.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: still getting the same error after installing the latest node snap package. 


$ node -v
v11.10.0


$ npm -v
6.8.0


$ nodejs -v
v8.10.0