# npm version is not compatible with node.js version

Tags: npm

I was trying to install mysql for npm with the comand `npm install mysql`, then I receive this error message:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.15.2
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
```

My version of node.js is 10.15.2 and the version of npm is 5.8.0. I think the problem is that they are not compatible. I was trying to update node, but I didn't succed in it.  Solutions?

I have switched to a newer version of nodejs, the twelve one, with this code:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The problem is that I still can't download mysql for npm. The message is:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dario/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dario/package.json'
npm WARN dario No description
npm WARN dario No repository field.
npm WARN dario No README data
npm WARN dario No license field.

+ mysql@2.17.1
updated 1 package and audited 32 packages in 1.447s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm)

Comment: It does not work, after the upgrade the version is always the 10.15.2 .

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657) to the linked duplicate question is the only one that still works perfectly with all native Ubuntu packages from Ubuntu Software.

Answer (score 8):

Well i face the same problem today after install ubuntu 19.10. and i solve this by updating `npm` using below command

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

For more details you can check this issue in github

[npm version issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1877)

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks, it works when I updated Node on my machine to the latest version 14.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest LTS Node.js on Ubuntu using the following command:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
```

This method is indicated in the official [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).

[Node.js binary distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)

If you need many versions of nodejs at the same time
Recommend using [nvm](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#nvm) ([git nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating))
install

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

**Example of use**

install 16 node

```
nvm install 16
```

list of installed

```
nvm ls
```

Selection of the version you need at the moment

```
nvm use 16
```

This way you can easily change the version. For compatibility with project packages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.