# Unable to install nodejs and npm correctly?

Tags: 18.04, nodejs, npm

I want to install nodejs its npm manager but when i try to execute its commands throwing the following error...I tried to install in different methods whatever i found in google and after installing also some packages from it are missing.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
```

Someone please help with proper way of installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js package is available in two releases:  **LTS release** and the **current release**. You can install any version you want. I am installing LTS version for this answer.

1. Add Node.js PPA

You will need `curl` to download the script, so first, install `curl` by typing `sudo apt install curl` in the `terminal`.

Once, `curl` is installed successfully, run the command to download and install the installer.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

2. Install `nodejs`

Now, run the below command install node on and Ubuntu using `apt`. This commmand will also install `npm` with `nodejs`. It will also install dependencies.

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Note: To check the version of `node` run the command

```
node -v
```

To check the version of `npm` run the command

```
npm -v
```

Comment: npm -v gives ": not foundrams/nodejs/npm: 3: /mnt/d/Programs/nodejs/npm:
: not foundrams/nodejs/npm: 5: /mnt/d/Programs/nodejs/npm:
/mnt/d/Programs/nodejs/npm: 6: /mnt/d/Programs/nodejs/npm: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")"

Answer (score 0):

just remove the nodejs

> sudo apt-get remove node
> restart machine and install again. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Follow this [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04) link to install nodejs, NPM, NVM. For UBUNTU related some documentation Digital Ocean has good documentation, it  will walk you trough every command.

Hop this Helps.

Comment: I followed all its installing but some error is there like npm install and others

Comment: can you tell the detail about error you are getting