# Nodejs update error

Tags: nodejs, npm

I tried that way:

root@ubuntu-14:/home/aldo# node -v
v9.11.2

root@ubuntu-14:/home/aldo# npm -v
5.6.0

$ sudo npm cache clean -f

$ sudo npm install -g n

$ sudo n 12.14.0

But is returning this error:

installing : node-v12.14.0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

Error: download preflight failed for '12.14.0' (https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.14.0/node-v12.14.0-linux-x86.tar.gz)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm)

Comment: I have answered a similar question here. https://askubuntu.com/a/1200174/890892

Comment: I don't even see the question here...