# I am trying to install forever on ubuntu

Tags: nodejs

I am new to node.js, I want to install forever on ubuntu. But unfortunately it gives me an error. See in the Picture :

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/faV9a.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faV9a.png)

Comment: The system says "This is an error with npm itself, report this error".  It sounds to me like you have an issue with your Node itself.  Possibly if your Node is too old this will happen (since it references Node 0.12)

Comment: Ok, i will update my node to latest version.

Comment: FYI, please copy screen contents as test, and paste the text into your question, instead of making a screenshot and pasting the screenshot, It is much more difficult to read a screenshot  compared to text. TY,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue after following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04) to install NodeJS.

I was able to get it work by installing a more recent NodeJS.

Follow these steps:

1. Uninstall NodeJS:
   `sudo apt purge nodejs`
   `sudo apt autoremove`
2. Install curl to download latest NodeJS setup:
   `sudo apt-get install curl`
3. Check out https://nodejs.org/ to see what is the latest LTS version.
4. Download it:
   `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -`
   (replace "12" with the current LTS major version number).
5. Install NodeJS (incl. npm):
   `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
6. Install forever:
   `sudo npm install forever -g`