# old version of npm is installed on running apt-get install npm on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nodejs, npm

Trying to install `npm` using command `sudo apt-get install npm` on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. expected `6.14.7` to be installed but `3.5.2` is being installed.

Comment: You need to install NodeJS from their repositories, the Ubuntu repositoreis have old NodeJS for 18.04.  Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm for more details and how to install newer NodeJS and npm.  (if I vote to close this it'll be instant-closed, so make sure the linked question actually solves your problem first)

Comment: @ThomasWard, It was working fine two days ago. with apt-get.

Comment: Doubtful as the node js versions are *ancient* in 18.04 and have been that way since its release (2018).

Comment: node version that I'm using is 8.10.0 and npm version is 6.14.7. I have been working on this project past 6 months and never ever used PPA or binary files. today I tried to setup my project on a new server and  this was the issue.

Comment: then your 'new server' had a locally installed NodeJS somewhere - that's the only way you got 'newer' NodeJS and npm.  I'm sorry, but there's no other explanation than someone installed/compiled newere NOdeJS and npm in your environment

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guide to installing newer version of NPM on Ubuntu 18.XX using a PPA:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04

You can also use NodeSource:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Comment: I tried using the NodeSource and install 12.x but on node js is installed with version 8.10.0.