# Not able to use nodejs with private user, but can use it with root user

Tags: 18.04, permissions, lubuntu, root, nodejs

I am using lubuntu. Installed nodejs with the .tar file in /opt directory through the root user. Using ''sudo su'' command. Now I am not able to use nodejs with my private user, whereas I can use it with again root user. How can I use nodejs with my private user also?

Comment: Grow up and install the native Ubuntu node snap package: https://askubuntu.com/a/594657/

Comment: okay, I will try

Comment: If you want the latest version you can install that snap package, and you can also install multiple versions of node.js alongside each other.

Comment: So, should I just uninstall the node version I installed using .tar file?

Comment: You get to choose whatever version(s) you want to install from a list. To show the list type `snap info node`

Comment: I will add node with snap, along with the node that I installed using the tar file