# auto start nodejs app

Tags: boot, nodejs, startup-applications

I want to run the command `node /home/makerio/Projects/red.js` when my computer boots. I added the command to `startup apps` but it gave me an error that indicates that for some reson, it was running an older version of nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).

Quoting from its README

> PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications
> with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep
> applications alive forever, to reload them without
> downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks

Basically it starts and manages the node process, at boot time or when the node process/app exists/breaks

```sh
# Installing pm2    
npm install -g pm2 # may require sudo

# Starting the app
pm2 start ~/Projects/red.js
pm2 save    # saves the running processes
            # if not saved, pm2 will forget
            # the running apps on next boot


# check status 
pm2 list

# IMPORTANT: If you want pm2 to start on system boot
pm2 startup # starts pm2 on computer boot
```

As for having an outdated node version, many guides exist [such as this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/635469)