# How to install node.js 16.13.1

Tags: software-installation, nodejs, npm

I want to use npm but it tells me on every command "npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0" so I want to update my node.js.
I performed `sudo apt update`
I tried to install it with `sudo apt install nodejs` but it tells me the latest version is already installed (but thats not true)

> nodejs ist schon die neueste Version (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1).

Translation: nodejs already is the latest version.
I downloaded the latest version 16.13.1 LTS as tar.gz and unpacked the files. I found the commands to use these file are

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

but where? In the unpacked folder is no folder named cofigure. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

The version of most applications available via apt in the LTS Ubuntu distribution repositories are usually not the latest. The reasons for this are answered in the question [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

If you want the latest, you might be better off installing the snap provided by the OpenJS Foundation, with the command:

```
sudo snap install node --classic
```

More details here:
https://snapcraft.io/install/node/ubuntu

Comment: I installed the snap but yet there is no difference. It's still saying "npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0". Do I need to use special commands to call the snap version?

Comment: Rather than using the snap, you might be better off adding the node repository and installing from there.
To remove the snap use the following command:
sudo snap remove node
Then follow the instructions here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm